# adding a new column SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like

```
select SUM(*) as "tot1" from table1 t, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.column=1

select SUM(*) as "tot2" from table1 t, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.column=2

select SUM(*) as "tot3" from table1 t, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.column=3
```

I want a query result look like this

```
 tot1     tot2     tot3

 500       600      3
```

Is this even possible? or is there any alternate solution for me to view these query in same table.

Comment: this is called pivot query

Comment: @parsa porahmad. can u show me a code that gives a result like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from 
(select SUM(*) as "tot1" from table1 t, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.column=1) a,

(select SUM(*) as "tot2" from table1 t, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.column=2) b,

(select SUM(*) as "tot3" from table1 t, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.column=3) c
```

Comment: There is no need for the outer `select * from` if this is MySQL. If it is postgresql, I can't remember if a `FROM` clause is mandatory.

Comment: It is indeed postgresql. And for the code, it gives me a syntax error from the column=1,. @attila

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select 
    SUM(CASE t1.column WHEN 1 THEN t1.column ELSE 0 END) as tot1, 
    SUM(CASE t1.column WHEN 2 THEN t1.column ELSE 0 END) as tot2, 
    SUM(CASE t1.column WHEN 3 THEN t1.column ELSE 0 END) as tot3 
from 
    table1 t, table2 t2 
where 
    t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: You mean to use `THEN t1.column` not `THEN 1`. Otherwise you're producing the _count_ per condition, not the `SUM()`. You need to actually sum up the values.

Comment: Remove the first then, because it's wrong :) This should be somewhat faster than the accepted one with subselects, by the way.

Comment: While this query looks better, determining how performance compares with the other solution depends on table structure and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> select SUM(t1.column=1) as "tot1",SUM(t1.column=2) as "tot2",
>   SUM(t1.column=) as "tot3" from table1 t, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id

Comment: This is going to effectively produce the _count_ for each condition, not the sum, since `SUM(column = 1)` will add `1` for each match, _not_ the column's actual value.

Comment: @Kino MySQL would permit this syntax (though the result would be wrong) but Postgresql won't.

Comment: Actually result is correct in MySQL, but might inded not work in postgresql. Its a short version  of `case when ... then ... else` supported by MySql. Since question is about postgresql (in didn't catch it), it does not apply for this question :|